# docker + wordpress install = error 500

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I try to install wordpress on a docker stack. Unfortunately i get an error 500 during the famous 5-minute installation.

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://0.0.0.0:8181/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2"
```

If i have a look on the logs, i get:

```
172.19.0.4 -  15/Feb/2017:05:21:44 +0000 "GET /v1/wp-admin/setup-config.php" 200
172.19.0.4 -  15/Feb/2017:05:22:37 +0000 "POST /v1/wp-admin/setup-config.php" 500
172.19.0.4 -  15/Feb/2017:05:23:17 +0000 "GET /v1/wp-admin/setup-config.php" 500
172.19.0.4 -  15/Feb/2017:05:24:01 +0000 "POST /v1/wp-admin/setup-config.php" 500
```

I get the same issue with apache + php + mariadb or nginx + php-fpm + mariadb (server, database and php seem to work well).
I don't use wordpress docker image to get more flexibility.

So i think about the permissions. I fix it.
In case, i remove the .htaccess and modify php.ini with:

```
post_max_size   64M
upload_max_filesize 64M
```

I fail imagination to solve the problem. Maybe an issue with the docker user who is not able to write the wp-config.php file (i don't know what could be the good practice).

Any idea to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance for the help.
jB

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

Please check if mysql extension is installed in php or not. If you see the *phpinfo()* you will get that.

To Install mysql write the below line in Dockerfile

*docker-php-ext-install mysql*

***Sample Docker file for php 5.6:***

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
# Install modules
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmcrypt-dev  \
    libicu-dev \
    mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring 
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

[image]

Comment: In my case it was `docker-php-ext-install mysqli`. e.g mysqli in stead of mysql